# Get an absolute path of a file from the user's local machine

Tags: django

I am using a django for a project where I upload files and store there file path to the media folder that is within my app.
Now is there a way in django that one can get the absolute path to the user's local machine rather than to the media directory within the app?
so it can return a path like

```
`C:\Users\Josh\Desktop\joshua.doc`
```

for a file stored on a users desktop and its namedjoshua.doc for instance.
your contributions and insights are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your 'media' directory is in the same directory as of your 'settings.py' file, then you can define following setting:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

And append the media path to the BASE_DIR path to get the absolute path of media file.

If you 'media' and 'settings.py' are in different directories then you may modifiy the `BASE_DIR` accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, I wanted a way to get absolute file not from media file but from user local machine? is that possible?

Comment: Oh okay, so you want to access a file located outside you django project. It won't be possible with Django's model FileField. You can create a new field type by inheriting FileField, but first of all why do you want to do that?

Comment: I want to store paths of all uploaded files..paths that are absolute to file location in the user local machine not the app folder